# Derivation of Mattig's Formula

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, cosmological-inflation

[Mattig's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mattig_formula) for any k:

[image: y]

How to derive this equation without using General Relativity?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math rather than posting an image. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you expect that this can be derived without using GR?